# C++ graphic on Geany + Xlib + BadAlloc = destroyed Friday

Tags: 12.04, c++

I have been trying to run a C++ program using Geany, and now, after ages of coding, I want to test the program. This is what comes up:

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I am feeling hopeless right now after 4 hours of searching Google. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems and you should try googling each one separately.
For the first problem:Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0"
See if this [post](https://github.com/amonakov/primus/issues/73) helps and try the following...

```
PRIMUS_libGL=/usr/'$LIB'/primus:/usr/lib64/nvidia:/usr/lib/nvidia${PRIMUS_libGL:-$(dirname `readlink -ne $0`)/'$LIB'}
```

This fixed a similar problem on a OpenSUSE 12.2 64 bit it might help you as well.

For the Second: X Error of failed request: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation) Major opcode of failed request

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15577540/2444126) out.

Comment: Did try, but nothing turns out to be right.

Wondering if reinstalling the whole OS would actually fix it. (if yes then...)

Comment: That might help, but did you ever test your code before and it worked on the machine you're using?

Comment: it works on another station (at my company) but on this... nah...

Comment: Gotcha, maybe a reinstallation is easiest but if its a problem that has to do with hardware/driver setup it might not help. I would try a live cd or maybe a VM to test your program.